# Angular AOT compiled app not tree shaking as expected

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-aot, tree-shaking, angular-aot

I have a module (`MyCommonModule`) with common components, services, etc that I plan to share between different angular applications.

This is an example of a simple app, that only imports `MyCommonModule` (but doesn't reference any of it in `AppComponent` yet):

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MyCommonModule } from "../common";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        MyCommonModule.forRoot()
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`MyCommonModule` is defined like this:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

// Components
import { SomeComponent } from "./components/some.component";
export * from "./components/some.component";

// Directives
import { SomeDirective } from "./directives/some.directive";
export * from "./directives/some.directive";

// Services
import { SomeService } from "./services/some.service";
export * from "./services/some.service";

// Models
export * from "./models/some.model";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        SomeComponent,
        SomeDirective
    ],
    providers: [],
    exports: [
        SomeComponent,
        SomeDirective
    ]
})
export class MyCommonModule {
    public static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: MyCommonModule,
            providers: [
                SomeService
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

When I run `ng build --environment=prod --target=production` I get a build that is AOT:d. If I analyze the output using `source-map-explorer` I can see that the resulting `main.*.bundle.js` and `vendor.*.bundle.js` contains all the services and components (and their references) in `MyCommonModule`, even though I didn't use any of it in my app.

Is that the expected behavior? Is tree shaking even enabled for angular cli apps?

Comment: You do use it in your app, though - you're importing `MyCommonModule` into `AppModule`, and `MyCommonModule` imports all of your services and components. If my understanding is correct, tree shaking works on the ES6 module level, not the Angular level - if you import a module somewhere, it's not going to get shaken out. Only things that aren't imported anywhere in your code will get removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"tree shaker" walks the dependency graph, top to bottom, and shakes out unused code like dead leaves in a tree. If your AppModule imports MyCommonModule the "tree shaker" can't know if you actually use it (In terms of JavaScript you use that code)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally give the following a try once you solved your problem:

```
ng build -prod --build-optimizer=true
```

(can't add comments yet, but that might be helpful)